# Trying to build a docker image form python app

Tags: python, docker

We are having this error. What does this mean?

```
--------------------
   5 |     COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt
   6 |     
   7 | >>> RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /code/requirements.txt
   8 |     
   9 |     COPY ./app /code/app
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /code/requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

Comment: Hello Sandy, can you try that command locally?

Comment: "Exit code 1" on its own doesn't usually mean more than "it didn't work"; the interesting part of the error will be before what you quoted.

Comment: @DavidMaze Yeah, that it my guess too. I am investigating what is in requirements.txt that causes it to exit.